# How to get Flutter WebSocket working with spring-boot backend?

Tags: java, flutter, spring-boot, websocket

I have tried many combinations of the values below, I have no idea why it isn't working. I don't even know if the problem is with frontend or backend setup. I pasted the relevant code parts below.

FLutter says the following when I try to connect (MYIPADDRESS is a valid IP address, the IP address of the pc):

```
WebSocketChannelException: WebSocketChannelException: WebSocketException: Connection to 'http://MYIPADDRESS:8080/topic/greetings#' was not upgraded to websocket
```

Here is the backend/spring-boot controller part:

```
@MessageMapping("/hello")
@SendTo("/topic/greetings")
public String send(final String message) throws Exception {
    return message;
}
```

Here is the backend/spring-boot configuration part:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
         registry.addEndpoint("/websocket").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

Here is the frontend/flutter part:

```
final channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
  Uri(
    scheme: "ws",
    host: "MYIPADDRESS",
    port: 8080,
    path: "/topic/greetings",
  ),
);
```